# Place a box behind first letter in chapter to stylize

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I would like to duplicate the first letter styling seen here, but not sure where to start. Essentially I need to adjust the size of the first letter in the chapter / section, and place a box behind it of smaller height and equal width. Is this easy to achieve?

I'm quite new to LaTex and really appreciate the time anyone takes to respond. Thanks!

[image: Lettering Example]

Comment: look at the `lettrine` package

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: You could also use wrapfig if you don't want to predefine the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it with `lettrine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[findent=3pt, nindent=0pt, ante=\rlap{\color{LightSalmon!50}\rule[-0.55\LettrineHeight]{\LettrineWidth}{0.65\LettrineHeight}} ]{I}{n} former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. If I understand correctly, the `\rlap` is overlapping the box you've drawn with `\rule` and the lettrine character. For `\rule` how did you settle on -0.55 (55% ?) of the lettrine height? Is there any particular to reason to use that instead of -0.50?

Comment: `\rlap`, so to say, places its contents without moving the insertion point. It's a plain TeX command; the LaTeX equivalent would be `\makebox[0pt][l]{contents}`. The value of .55 was found by trial and error, but you may very well experiment and find a different value will look better.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I tried using tikz and hangindent (it's only one paragraph).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\bigletter}[2]% #1=number lines, #2=letter
{\sbox1{\resizebox{!}{\dimexpr #1\baselineskip-0.4\baselineskip}{#2}}%
  \sbox0{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[red,opacity=.5] ({-0.5\wd1},{-0.3\ht1}) rectangle ({0.5\wd1},{.3\ht1});
      \node[inner sep=0pt] {\usebox1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \hangindent=\dimexpr \wd0+2pt\relax
  \hangafter=-#1
  \noindent\llap{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \baselineskip-#1\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox0}%
    \hspace{2pt}}%
\strut\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\bigletter{3}{L}orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cura-
bitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]